# Adding background image to ArcGIS online Popup

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

I am trying to make a custom popup for a storymap template by changing the CSS.  The background colors can be changed but is there a way to add an image to the main area with the attributes instead of a color background.   I have tried

```
.esriPopup.chrome .titlePane,
.dj_ie7 .esriPopup.chrome .titlePane .title{
    back-ground image: URL (/images/image.png)
}
```

and

```
 .esriPopup.chrome .titlePane {
    back-ground image: URL (/images/image.png)
}
```

Nothing has worked.  Is this possible and if so where would I put the back - ground image code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to target the `contentPane` to add background images to the popup. Something like [this sample](http://jsbin.com/xiqaxe/1/edit?css,output).

```
.contentPane {
  background: url("//js.arcgis.com/3.14/esri/images/map/logo-med.png");
}
```

Then adjust your `no-repeat`, `repeat-x`, `repeat-y` as needed. [MDN resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  The image shows up but now I lost the control buttons (restore, arrows) in the title.